# How can I remove UIVisualEffect from the current view ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I need when I am clicked on the close button back to the previous view, but I want to erase the blur, I can't reuse the previous screen.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86wWh.png)

Comment: Is this a third-party Library? not enough info to help u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UIVisualEffectView` subclasses `UIView`,are you added the visual effect view to `self.view` as a subview . if you no need use  (the `UIView` hidden property) or remove it from the subviews

for the name of `var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!` , you can use for remove in the following way

```
 blurView.removeFromSuperview()
```

or you can remove as like

```
  for subview in blurView.subviews {
    if subview is UIVisualEffectView {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will remove blur's content too.